Fastest way to calculate zonal statistics on millions of small polygons and storing results as JSON
I have a dataset with couple million farm polygons (around 2.5 million and only expected to grow in the future), and I need to calculate the NDVI for these farm polygons, with some basic stats (Average, Min, Max), and store the results in a PostGIS table as a simplified JSON (rounding off the NDVI values to the nearest 0.05).
Currently I am using a combination of rasterio and gdal in python to clip these polygons with respect to preprocessed NDVI images, but the process is very slow. On average, I am getting 4 new NDVI images each month, the process is slow enough that I have not been able to clear a backlog to calculate historical NDVI values.
I have implemented Multi-Processing in Python to limited success. The current stack I'm working with has python, gdal and postgis setup, but I am willing to consider other frameworks or languages if the performance boost is significant enough.

I haven't, from what little experience I have with PostGIS rasters, each raster is stored as a separate table, and I have too many different NDVI rasters to be using storing each as a table.

Related: Clipping tiled raster with polygon using PostGIS, Performance in calculating raster statistics in PostGIS, Intersecting a raster with a polygon using PostGIS.

I have similar workflows, and I recently did some testing to compare the performance of different python solutions to calculate "zonal statistics".
At the time of this last update (2024-09-28), the exactextract library gives me the best performance. It also has very powerful features to control which pixels to use (and how much) to e.g. exclude the impact of mixels (mixed pixels), which might be important for your use case.
The benchmark can be found here.
The following image shows the timings to calculate zonal statistics for 5.000 agricultural parcels for some libraries:

